# Getting a session not created exception

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have started getting the following exception when running a Webdriver application in a Windows 10 64 bit environment using Chrome.

**System.InvalidOperationException: session not created exception from disconnected: not connected to DevTools.
(Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.76)  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (33)**

It appears to have started after the latest Chrome update (56), and I’m using the latest Chromedriver version 2.27, as advised in other posts.

Any advice please.

Comment: I have the same issue too.  I'm using safari as an alternative on Mac.